# How to use sed or awk to align the first occurrence of a symbol

Tags: text, replace, awk, sed, gawk

I have lines on the form

```
hello world#it#is#a#nice#day
once upon a time...
yes#and#no
good#bye
```

I want align the *first* `#`-character (if any). If I do

```
$ sed 's/#/\t#/1'
```

a tab is inserted before the first `#`:

```
hello world     #it#is#a#nice#day
once upon a time...
yes     #and#no
good    #bye
```

Not very nice! I want the output to be more like:

```
hello world     #it#is#a#nice#day
once upon a time...
yes             #and#no
good            #bye
```

I would like to achieve this in bash with either sed or awk, but cannot work out how.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?  Do you know in advance how wide the longest input is going to be?

Comment: I do not know the position of the rightmost, first occurrence of `#` across the lines. This means the solution must involve two passes. My solution is an overkill Java program, but I was hoping for a short-and-sweet one-liner in bash. I have tried googling the solution (unsuccessfully) and I have started learning awk (work in progress that is slow and time-consuming), hence my post here. Inserting tabs is the best I have so far (using sed).

Comment: (I think you mean "leftmost".)

Comment: @tripleee - Thanks, this is far better than my tabs.  I need to somehow pull out the value "25" by passing over the lines. I'm working on solving this bit. And yes, *leftmost*, not rightmost!

Comment: You'll want to reload, you have two answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd trick the `column` utility into doing this. You'll need a character that's not in the text as a marker. I'll use `\x01` (binary 1, "start of header" in ASCII) and a bash shell extension (`$'' strings`) to make this work, but any character works as long as it's not in the input data.

Then:

```
sed 's/#/\x01#/' filename | column -t -s $'\x01'
```

This will first place the marker before the first `#`, then columnate the data using `\x01` as separator.

Comment: One little detail however is that a line without a `#`-symbol is placed in full in the first column. Preferably I would align the `#` only according to lines that contain at least one `#`. Relatively small detail though.

Comment: Hmm...I suppose you could do something along the lines of `sed '/#/!s/^/#\x02/; s/#/\x01#/' filename | column -tns $'\x01' | sed 's/^ *#\x02//'`, i.e., move lines that don't contain a `#` to the second column (by prepending a `#`) and moving them back to the front afterwards. This requires a second marker character if lines can begin with `#`. On the one hand this is probably not a problem for text, esp. because the marker is only a marker in this specific context, on the other you don't want to drown in forbidden characters, so this technique is not something to extend indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the same input file twice, and calculate the max width on the first round through.  A common Awk idiom is `NR==FNR` which is true when you are processing the first file in a group of many (the overall line number equals the line number within this file).

```
awk -F '#' 'NR==FNR { if (NR==1 || length($1) > max) max=length($1); next }
    { printf "%*s%s\n", -max, $1, substr($0, length($1)+1) }' file file
```

The use of `*` in a `printf` width specifier is probably not easy to google -- it says to read the width from the next argument (consuming arguments as you process the format string).  A negative width is left-justified (positive would get you right-aligned space padding).